# Sci-fi short story about a magician who ends up in an alien teleportation device while performing a disappearing act

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, teleportation

Trying to remember name of a story in a sci-fi anthology about a magician who ends up in an alien teleportation device while performing a cheesy disappearing act.

He is a Vegas-type magician and one day uses his cabinet for his cheesy disappearing act, but while in the hidden compartment of the cabinet he suddenly finds himself somewhere else and he sees some kind of alien creature in front of him and throws his arms up in terror. The story jumps back to the audience and the cabinet slowly opened and the magicians smoldering and dismembered body falls onto the stage.

The story then cuts to an alien spaceship where two creatures are in front of a console with a flashing light, both of them using their elongated tentacles and large claw like limbs to twist and press buttons. One says to the other "What happened?" and the other replies "The transporter malfunctioned. It picked up some strange creature which roared and threw up its limbs in an attack stance so I used the uranium wave emitter to exterminate it. Damn Bugs."

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this story, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Is the text *"The transporter malfunctioned. It picked up some strange creature which roared and threw up its limbs in an attack stance so I used the uranium wave emitter to exterminate it. Damn Bugs."* a quote that you remember exactly, or do you mean the alien says something along those lines?